# iPhone 3.0 Compass: how to get a heading?

Tags: iphone, cllocation

I'm relatively new to Objective-C and really don't know much about it yet, so I apologise for what is probably a really amateurish question.

I'm trying to get the magnetic heading from CLHeading and CLLocationDirection.  However I'm getting compile errors for this line of code:

```
locationLabel.text = [[[location course] magneticHeading] stringValue];
```

The errors are:

```
warning: invalid receiver type 'CLLocationDirection'  
error: cannot convert to a pointer type
```

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong here.  Please help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are the steps needed to use the compass.

1) check the availability: if the `headingAvailable` property of the location manager is YES, then you can use the compass.

2) use the location manager method  `-(void) startUpdatingHeading` to begin receiving the information you are searching for

3) actually retrieve this information using the delegate method (do not forget to set yourself as the delegate)

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For Google's sake:

The headingAvailable property has been deprecated since iO4.  There is now a headingAvailable class method that returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

magneticHeading is of CLLocationDirection type, which is simply a typedef for the primitive data type "double". In your example you are trying to send a message to something that is not an object ! You should simply format the double like so:

`locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Heading %.3f", [[location course] magneticHeading]];`

Comment: Thanks, this was where I was getting really confused.  I need to learn more about typedefs I guess.

Answer (score 1):

How are you allocating and initializing `location`? Make sure `location` is defined as a `(CLLocationDirection *)` and not just a `(CLLocationDirection)`.