# Save a text file in the Media folder of the IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey , I created a text file and I want save in the media folder not in the root folder. How I can do this?

Comment: Here is another related comment that gives you the tips on how to read the values from the compass, which could possibly help get you on your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043740/iphone-3-0-compass-how-to-get-a-heading/1044444#1044444

Comment: I have the three value of compass, Now I need to know how to create an image (arrow) for illustrating the value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Now I need to know how to create an image (arrow) for illustrating the value.

That's a big topic.  In a nutshell, you need to subclass [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and implement drawing code in the [drawRect](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDGJHF): method of your subclass to implement a compass pointer.  I've not done this on iPhone, but I have dome it on OS X.  I expect the principles are the same.

The first thing I did was move the point (0, 0) to the centre of the view.  I then defined a path that drew the compass arrow in a straight up and down direction.  And I used a transform to rotate it to the correct angle.

I suggestr you read the [Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [View Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) before proceeding.